# Where to get Paytm CSRF Token

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, csrf, csrf-protection

Paytm Using CSRF token for few of his API. I want to know from where
we can get the CSRF token for the Paytm. So that I will be able to hit
the API.

Also, it will be helpful if somebody let me know which format or
algorithm Paytm using for CSRF token. Is the CSRF token different from the Value of the CSRF provided in the HTML form of Paytm?

Because the token saved in HTML form of Paytm is different from the
token Paytm using for the API hit. Or Paytm using some technique or
algorithm to change that HTML form Token in some encryption and then
use?

Comment: Specify which API you are using?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Akshay, i am using the Seller create shipment API :-
https://fulfillment.paytm.com/v1/merchant/24756/fulfillment/autoCreate/57694582?&client=web

Comment: @AkshayGohil any update?

Comment: I didn't find any official api docs online http://paywithpaytm.com/developer/discussion/topic/seller-api-paytm/  What is the source of the api you shared? Can you share if there are any docs? and CSRF token is generated different each time you load a page.